# Repository pattern and shared entities

Tags: php, design-patterns, architecture, repository-pattern

I'm considering using the repository design pattern for data abstraction, I'm using Phalcon PHP framework and using the following structure:

```
ModelA
    |- Entity
        |- Entity1.php
        |- Entity2.php
        |- Entity3.php
    |- Repository
        |- RepositoryA.php
    |- Service
        |- ServiceA.php
```

Now if I had to use the same Entity2.php in another ModelB for instance, I would lose the most convenient use of the repository pattern, which is that I can change the data source for Entity2.php only by modifying RepositoryA.php, instead of worrying about who also might have used that entity.
If I didn't allow for direct access to entities, I can't perform joins across multiple repositories.

What is the best approach to handle this issue?

Comment: Why do you think you will *lose the most convenient use of the repository pattern*?

Answer (score 3):

From your description, I'm going to assume that ModelA/Repository/RepositoryA.php is a concrete implementation.
If I am understanding your question correctly, you want to also have ModelB/Repository/RepositorA.php, both of which are accessing the same database table(s) to provide the same entity (say, ModelA/Entity/EntityA.php).

One thing you could do is turn both of those RepositoryA classes into interfaces, which you then implement elsewhere with one concrete class, something like this:

```
ModelA
    |- Entity
        |- Entity1.php
        |- Entity2.php
        |- Entity3.php
    |- Repository
        |- RepositoryA.php (interface, for dealing with ModelA\Entity\Entity1)
    |- Service
        |- ServiceA.php (depends on ModelA\Repository\RepositoryA)
ModelB
    |- Repository
        |- RepositoryB.php (interface, for dealing with ModelA\Entity\Entity1)
    |- Service
        |- ServiceB.php (depends on ModelB\Repository\RepositoryB)
Infrastructure
    |- Repository
        |- ConcreteEntity1Repository (concrete class that implements both RepositoryA and RepositoryB interfaces.  Somehow, an instance of this is passed to both ServiceA and ServiceB (dependancy injection or whatever you like))
```

This way, you can separate what concrete implementation you are using from your service layer, giving you more flexibility to change things around when you need to. (As an added bonus, this would make it much easier to do things like unit testing your code.)

With this approach, you are effectively using the same repository inside both models, but without creating any coupling between them. Depending on your system architecture, it could be rather complex to set things up this way and it may be overkill for the situation.

An alternative approach could be to not make RepositoryA and RepositoryB an interface, but turn them into concrete classes that delegate their work, either by passing a common "Entity1Repository" to them (and having RepositoryA and RepositoryB wrap the calls they need), or by creating an abstract base class that they both extend which contains any common functionality.

This has the added advantage that you can also add things specific to one model, without it being a part of the other model. (For example, ModelA\Repository\RepositoryA can have a function findRelatedTo(Entity3 $entity3), without forcing ModelB to know what an Entity3 is.)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar requirement with one of my projects. I went with creating a base class that repositories can extend just like one of Jory Geert's solutions. Here's [a sample starter project](https://github.com/bronsonpelayo/phalcon-starter) I created using Phalcon 2.0 with Doctrine 2. Implementation is not that clean yet and documentation is still work in progress, but it should give you an idea.